# Remove collection/model

Tags: model, mongoose, keystonejs

How can we remove a collection registered using keystone register method?

I tried to remove the model without success, then I tried manually using node console:
But now even if I remove the collection using:

```
mongoose.connection.db.dropCollection('news', function(err, result) {console.log(err)});
```

my collection is automatically recreated somehow by keystonejs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to drop a whole model? That's application logic no? You can keep the collection just empty it out instead.

Comment: It appear in the admin interface automagically

Comment: did you use a generator? If you want to remove a model remove `model.js` from the `models` directory. And wipe your db manually.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I thought I tried that before, but my coffeescript watch must have regenerated the model before I flushed the database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove a model remove model.js from the models directory. And wipe your db manually.